# Flutter customized list

Tags: flutter

I am new to learning flutter and want to make an app with a customized list view. Is there any way to set headers and footers of a listView? Here is an example of the goal I have in mind (video is from the iOS Contacts app):

[image]

Here's another image for reference:

[image]

To be specific I want to know if there are any widgets other than list view that can be used to achieve this behavior like how the header stays on the screen till the contents are no longer visible. There does not seem to be any inbuilt header and footer property of listview. Will I have to achieve this behavior using column (text(header), listview, text(footer)) and repeat that for the number of sections I want? This method doesn't seem that efficient. What if instead of the listview between sections I want a gridview that is scrollable vertically? Are there any packages that can be used for this instead of widgets.

Comment: you can make it with sliver widget. But for simple, you may try this package https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers